# Is it possible to do a ListViewItem array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listview

Is it possible to declare a `ListViewItem` *array*? E.g.

```
ListViewItem[] arrayItems;
```

- If it's *possible*, how can I *populate* the array?
- Is it possible to have the array which is not *fixed size*?

Comment: You can have an array of any type and initialize it inline or using a loop. Or get items of list view in the array using `listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToArray()`. What's your real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for `List<ListViewItem>`, not for array (`ListViewItem[]`):

```
List<ListViewItem> myItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

// Just add items when required; 
// have a look at Remove, RemoveAt, Clear as well
myItems.Add(new ListViewItem("Text 1"));

// When you want read/write the item do as if you have an array
ListViewItem myItem = myItems[0];
```

You can use *Linq* to obtain items from existing `ListView`:

```
myItems = listView1.Items
  .OfType<ListViewItem>()
  .ToList();
```

or append existing list:

```
List<ListViewItem> myItems = new List<ListViewItem>();
...
myItems.AddRange(listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes ! It is possible to declare a List as an array.

For **Specified length** use below:

```
ListViewItem[] arrayItems = new ListViewItem[5];

arrayItems[0] = new ListViewItem("Text1");
arrayItems[1] = new ListViewItem("Text2");
// so on
```

For **Unspecified length** use below:

```
List<ListViewItem> arrayItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

arrayItems.Add(new ListViewItem("Text1"));
arrayItems.Add(new ListViewItem("Text2"));

// When you want to pass it as array, use arrayItems.ToArray();
```

Or if you have some list of objects with some text Property:

```
List<ListViewItem> arrayItems = dataSourceObject.Select(x => new 
                                                  ListViewItem(x.TextProperty)).ToList();
```

Comment: But in that case i need to specify on many items I want, I wanted to keep adding them in a loop but with no length conditioning me

Answer (score 0):

If using Visual Studio and MFC:

```
        array<ListViewItem^>^ listviewarray = gcnew array<System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^>(100);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            listviewarray[i] = gcnew ListViewItem("Text1"); // create each sensor listview element
        }
```

Comment: This looks more like C++-CLR ('managed' C++ code) rather than the C# that the question is tagged with.